# How to invoke a method in a class always when the class is accessed - like a reaction?

Tags: c#, class

I am working on a C# net micro framework project, in particular an I2C bus class.

I have several different I2C devices each defined in separate classes which contain all of the devices' unique methods. In my case, I can only have ONE I2CDevice object defined and to switch to another I2C device, I have to change the I2CDevice.Config = DeviceConfig.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
Class Device1 
-DeviceConfig1
-Method 1
-Method 2
-Method 3

Class Device2
-DeviceConfig2
-Method 1
-Method 2
-Method 3


Main Program
{
I2cBus = new I2CDevice(configuration)
Device1.Method1
Device2.Method3
}
```

When switching between devices, I need to change the I2CDevice.Config property. I'm looking for an elegant way such that whenever I call a Method for a device, that the I2CBus.Config is automatically changed. Is there a way that I don't need to re-type this config code in each method? Have a separate internal method that's called each time I access any of those methods?

I hope my description is clear.

Update, As an alternative, is there a way I can have my make my I2C Bus class and then ADD the devices to the this class? Then To access The Devices, I would Do something like

```
I2CBus.AddDevice(Device1ObjectClass)
I2CBus.AddDevice(Device2ObjectClass)
I2CBus.Device1.Method1
I2CBus.Device2.Method2
```

I still have the same problem that I need to "automatically" switch the I2C configuration between Different Device calls.

Comment: So when you call `Device1.Method1`, `I2cBus` uses `DeviceConfig1`, and when you call `Device2.Method3`, `I2cBus` uses `DeviceConfig2`? I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Brandon I think he is talking about setting the I2C configuration depending on the latest method called. If it was class 1, the configuration in I2C must be the class1 configuration

Comment: @rpax I kind of figured that might be it.

Comment: If `configuration` is a reference type (i.e. an object) then `Device1.Method1` and `Device2.Method3` can both manipulate properties in it if they are passed (or have access to) a reference of it. For example: `Device2.Method3(I2cBus.Configuration)`

Comment: You should look for some aspect framework like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects). It enables such functionality easily. Though I'm not sure if `PostSharp` supports Micro Framework.

Comment: Yes @Brandon . When I call a method from Device1 I need to switch the configuration as well. I can pass the I2C device object into the Device1 and Device2 Classes on creation, but then I need the have the I2Cbus.Config=DeviceConfig1 or 2 within each method. I'm seeing if there's a more elegant way so I don't need to code this in each method. Lots of duplicate code. or even an internal method call. still lots of duplicate code.

Comment: @slugster I pass the I2CDevice object into each device class, so the class can update the I2cDevice.config property, but for each method, I need to invoke the configuration change/checker, to make sure the configuration is set to communicate with that device.

Comment: Any Ideas? @Brandon

Comment: @GisMofx I think I can hack something together but it will most-likely be less than ideal. That or the cognitive load on it will be moderately high. I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
   private Device1 _device1;
   public Device1 device1
   {
      get
      {
           happensEveryTimeDeviceIsAccessed();
           return _device1;

       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to make it a little more automatic with how that works.  For example, `Device1.Method1(); Device2.Method3();` will the the only calls. Without adding duplicate code in each method, something, ideally "automatic", should check the I2Cbus Configuration and make it correct if there's a device change.

Comment: do device1 and device2 share a base class or are they the same class?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with, and I'm not afraid to admit that it's garbage because you're still not able to have your `I2CBus` intrinsically know what to do. It *kind of* works but, as I mentioned, it's all I have.

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DeviceConfiguration GetConfiguration();
}

public abstract class DeviceParent : IDevice
{
    public DeviceParent(DeviceConfiguration aConfig)
    {
        myConfig = aConfig; 
    }

    #region IDevice Members

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual DeviceConfiguration GetConfiguration() //This could also simply be a property, not sure what you want to do with it.
    {
        return myConfig;
    }

    #endregion

    protected DeviceConfiguration myConfig;

}

public class DeviceConfiguration
{
    public DeviceConfiguration()
    {

    }
}

public class Device : DeviceParent
{
    public Device(DeviceConfiguration aConfig) : base(aConfig) { }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class Device2 : DeviceParent
{
    public Device2(DeviceConfiguration aConfig) : base(aConfig) { }

    public void SomeMethod2()
    {

    }
}

public class I2CBus : IEnumerable<IDevice>
{

    private List<IDevice> myDevices;
    private DeviceConfiguration currentConfiguration;

    public enum NonExistantDeviceBehaviour
    {
        ReturnNull,
        AddToOurselves
    }

    public NonExistantDeviceBehaviour NoDeviceBehaviour; //Defines what should happen in the event that we're indexed by a device that we don't contain yet.

    public IDevice this[IDevice index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!myDevices.Exists(d => d.Name == index.Name))
            {
                switch (NoDeviceBehaviour)
                {
                    case NonExistantDeviceBehaviour.ReturnNull:
                        return null;
                    case NonExistantDeviceBehaviour.AddToOurselves:
                        myDevices.Add(index);
                        break;
                }
            }

            currentConfiguration = index.GetConfiguration();

            return myDevices.Find(d => d.Name == index.Name);

        }
    }


    public I2CBus()
    {
        currentConfiguration = null;
        myDevices = new List<IDevice>(); //Ensures our list is never null
    }


    #region IEnumerable<IDevice> Members

    public IEnumerator<IDevice> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myDevices.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So all I did pretty much was add the index to the `I2CBus` class, which allows you to use this syntax:

```
I2CBusInstance[Device1]
```

However, you still have to cast to the type you're passing to that index to get access to that type's methods anyway, which is why this solution isn't ideal. Here is the usage:

```
I2CBus i2cb = new I2CBus();

Device device = new Device(new DeviceConfiguration());
Device2 device2 = new Device2(new DeviceConfiguration());

i2cb.NoDeviceBehaviour = I2CBus.NonExistantDeviceBehaviour.AddToOurselves;

(i2cb[device] as Device).SomeMethod();
```

Hope that helps a little... I'll be watching this question a while because I'm incredibly intrigued now.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Unfortunately, I cannot use this specific example because the netMF framework doesn't support Generics... _yet_. I'm still looking for another solution and have been tossing this around in my head. I like your idea of having a base class..maybe a State Pattern approach or something similar could accomplish this. Still thinking. What if each device class had an instance of the I2C bus class in it?..hmm